# Jupyter Colab: Host key verification failed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssh, google-colaboratory

I am trying to connect through a ssh tunnel to mysql DB on aws but when I run the following command in a call on colab.research.google (https://colab.research.google.com/) I have the following error message: `Host key verification failed.`

This is the command I am trying to run in a cell:

`!ssh -i "edb-dev.pem" ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.af-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com` 
Can you guys try to explain me what is missing?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like HTTPS, SSH provides a mechanism to cryptographically identify a remote host.  Each SSH host has a pair of *host keys* and these keys are used to "prove" you're connecting to the host you think you are.    But unlike HTTPS, which relies on predistributed CA certificates to assert trustworthiness of novel  https server certificates, SSH does not use certificate signatures.

Instead, each host is trusted by associating its public key with the hostname, either before the connection is made, or just-in-time as part of an interactive process which prompts the user to accept or reject an unknown host key.

In your case, you don't already have a copy of the host key, and the cell doesn't have an interactive terminal on which to prompt you to accept, so ssh doesn't trust the key by default.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/104932/how-do-i-know-a-new-host-key-is-safe-to-accept describes a number of options you have to work around this issue.  I'm going to go into detail into one that's probably the right choice for you.

I'm going to walk you through obtaining the key for your EC2 instance and then adding it to the list of known hosts so that it will be trusted.  Start with the following command run on a local terminal that is allowed to contact the host over ssh:

```
ssh-keyscan -H ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.af-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

This will spit out a line or two containing the public keys identify that host.

Now, copy those public key(s) out.  In a command before making the ssh connection, do something like this:

```
cat >> ~/.ssh/known-hosts <<-eof
paste-your-host-ssh-public-key-lines-here
eof
```

That will write the public keys of your host into `~/.ssh/kwown_hosts` so that when you `ssh` to that host in the future, its public key will be trusted.

One caveat here, if the ec2 instance comes and goes, you have to make sure the ssh host keys are consistent.  Fresh new instances from upstream AMIs do not have ssh host keys so they generate them at first boot.  Since you have an IP hard coded in your script I am guessing your EC2 instance will not be replaced any time soon.

Alternative: Ignore host keys.  You can configure SSH to ignore host key checking.  This is generally ill advised especially if the IP address you're connecting to might be reused in the future, which is the case in EC2.

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  ... ...
```

This is a lazy practice which basically equates to you saying "I can't be bothered to make sure I am sshing ito the computer I think I'm sshing into".  You might proceeed to send confidential data to an untrusted host, for example.   In practice this would require the untrusted host to also allow you to authenticate but it's certainly possible a nefarious actor might do so.